# Less strict alternative to parfor in matlab?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have code that is structurally similar to the following in Matlab:

```
bestConfiguration = 0;
bestConfAwesomeness = 0;

for i=1:X
    % note that providing bestConfAwesomeness to the function helps it stop if it sees the current configuration is getting hopeless anyway
    [configuration, awesomeness] = expensive_function(i, bestConfAwesomeness);
    if awesomeness > bestConfAwesomeness
        bestConfAwesomeness = awesomeness;
        bestConfiguration = configuration;
    end
end
```

There is a bit more to it but the basic structure is the above. `X` can get *very* large. I am trying to make this code run in parallel, since `expensive_function()` takes a long time to run.

The problem is that Matlab won't let me just change `for` to `parfor` because it doesn't like that I'm updating the best configuration in the loop.

So far what I've done is:

```
[allConfigurations, allAwesomeness] = deal(cell(1, X));

parfor i=1:X
    % note that this is not ideal because I am forced to use 0 as the best awesomeness in all cases
    [allConfigurations{i}, allAwesomeness{i}] = expensive_function(i, 0);
end

for i=1:X
    configuration = allConfigurations{i};
    awesomeness = allAwesomeness{i};
    if awesomeness > bestConfAwesomeness
        bestConfAwesomeness = awesomeness;
        bestConfiguration = configuration;
    end
endfor
```

This is better in terms of time it takes to run; however, for large inputs it takes huge amounts of memory because all the configurations are always saved. Another problem is that using `parfor` forces me to always provide `0` as the best configuration even though better ones might be known.

Does Matlab provide a better way of doing this?

Basically, if I didn't have to use Matlab and could manage the threads myself, I'd have one central thread which gives jobs to workers (i.e. make them run `expensive_function(i)`) and once a worker returns, look at the data it produced and compare it to the best found so far and update it accordingly. There would be no need to save all the configurations which seems to be the only way to make `parfor` work.

Is there a way to do the above in Matlab?

Comment: To be able to use prior knowledge when calling `expensive_function`, you could split up the range of `parfor` into smaller sweeps (e.g., `i=1:floor(X/2)`, followed by `i=floor(X/2):X`) and use the best results of the first sweeps to seed the following calls to `expensive_function`. Note that the feasibility of this solution depends on the tradeoff between the runtime savings due to informed calls to `expensive_function` and the savings due to having one single `parfor` compared to having multiple sequential `parfor`s.

Comment: @H.Muster: I was thinking about this, but it's not ideal because the `expensive_function` could take a long time for some inputs, i.e. the first sweep could unnecessarily be waiting for a small part of it to complete when it could already be running jobs from the other part

Comment: As I said, it depends on the tradoff. As a workaround, `expensive_function` could save some of its results to file. Then, on each call, the function could check whether result-files are already available and, if so, make use of this prior knowledge.

Comment: Your loop iterations are not independent because you're using knowledge from previous iterations (i.e. bestConfAwesomeness). This is not a specifically MATLAB problem - PARFOR is simply defending you against what would otherwise be a race condition.

Comment: @Edric: yes, but that bestConfAwesomeness is not strictly needed; it is only there to speed it up a bit, not providing it won't change the output. I.e. if you pass 0 all the time it will give the exact same result, but slower. This is a Matlab problem because in most other languages you could just do what I described in the last paragraph.

Comment: Your last paragraph describes pretty much a situation where you have the MATLAB client run lots of PARFOR loops in succession and updates stuff in between PARFORs. See also my answer where you can do pretty much the same thing but with probably better load balancing using SPMD.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `bestConfAwesomeness` each time round the loop means that the iterations of your loop are not order-independent, hence why `PARFOR` is unhappy. One approach you could take is to use `SPMD` and have each worker perform `expensiveFunction` in parallel, and then communicate to update `bestConfAwesomeness`. Something like this:

```
bestConfiguration = 0;
bestConfAwesomeness = 0;
spmd
  for idx = 1:ceil(X/numlabs)
    myIdx = labindex + ((idx-1) * numlabs);
    % should really guard against myIdx > X here.
    [thisConf, thisAwesome] = expensiveFunction(myIdx, bestConfAwesomeness);
    % Now, we must communicate to see if who is best
    [bestConfiguration, bestAwesomeness] = reduceAwesomeness(...
        bestConfiguration, bestConfAwesomeness, thisConf, thisAwesome);
  end
end

function [bestConf, bestConfAwesome] = reduceAwesomeness(...
    bestConf, bestConfAwesome, thisConf, thisAwesome)
% slightly lazy way of doing this, could be optimized
% but probably not worth it if conf & awesome both scalars.
allConfs = gcat(bestConf);
allAwesome = gcat(thisAwesome);
[maxThisTime, maxLoc] = max(allAwesome);
if maxThisTime > bestConfAwesome
    bestConfAwesome = maxThisTime;
    bestConf = allConfs(maxLoc);
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the kind of control over your threads is possible with Matlab. However, since `X` is very large, it may be worth doing the following, which costs you one more iteration of `expensiveFunction`:

```
%# calculate awesomeness
parfor i=1:X
   [~,awesomeness(i)] = expensiveFunction(i);
end
%# find the most awesome i
[mostAwesome,mostAwesomeIdx] = min(awesomeness);
%# get the corresponding configuration
bestConfiguration = expensiveFunction(mostAwesomeIdx);
```

Comment: Thanks, true, this might help in keeping the memory cost down. The reason I was looking for a better option was that it would also be useful to me to have some way of passing the best known awesomeness found so far to the expensive function which is possible with a `for` but not a `parfor`. Edited question now to reflect that (I forgot to mention that previously)